# "Solving Environment" during `conda install -c <my_channel> tensorflow` takes 3+ min but changing the name a bit reduces the time significantly

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I am writing a custom conda package for tensorflow. When I name the package "tensorflow" it takes it more than 3 minutes to get past the "solving environment" part but if I change the package name even a little bit, to "tensorflowp3" it loads in around 10 seconds. 
I am using the commands -

`conda install -c <my_channel> tensorflow`

`conda install -c <my_package> tensorflowp3`

I am not sure why setting a slightly different package name causes such a significant time change. I am specifying which channel the package should be loaded from in the command as well. I have tried doing the same with locally stored packages using the --use-local tag as well but it still behaves the same way as with the channel name. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Probably the solver has to do a lot more dependency checking for a package named `tensorflow` which is also present on the default channel (or another channel you have configured). You'll need to go through and profile the Conda code if you want a true answer to this though...

Comment: @darthbith Thanks a lot! But will the solver still check on other channels even if I specify my custom channel using the -c tag? Also, is there any solution for this delay other than changing the name of the package? I would really prefer to keep the name same.

Answer (score 6):

I solved by doing this

1. open `Anaconda Navigator` application
2. select `Environment` from menu
3. choose the environment you wanna use (base enviroment if you don't use multiple enviroments)
4. `Update index`
5. Click on channels and remove all eventual channel, but `default`

Now, for me it takes a reasonable abount of time to install a new packet.

Comment: How would I do this on linux using a terminal?

Comment: Don't know about terminal, but anaconda navigator is installed in linux too as `anaconda-navigator`.

Comment: not sure if the same but there is a `conda clean  --index-cache` command. Not sure about removing channels without knowing their aliases